# Напечатать все перестановки чисел 1..n

Tags: c#

Напечатать все перестановки чисел 1..n (то есть последовательности длины n, в которые каждое из чисел 1..n входит по одному разу).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это классический алгоритм, во многих учебниках даётся описание. Поскольку вы не уточняли, что конкретно нужно — вот вам самая простая для понимания реализация:

```
void Main()
{
    char[] a = "123".ToCharArray();
    Permute(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
}

void Permute(char[] a, int i, int n)
{
    int j;

    if (i == n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new string(a));
    }
    else
    {
        char temp;
        for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
        {
            // swap(a[i], a[j]);
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;

            Permute(a, i + 1, n);

            // swap(a[i], a[j]);
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И классическая картинка-пояснение (мысленно подставьте вместо строки "123" "ABC"):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Чел, ты лучший! ОЧЕНЬ БЛАГОДАРЕН!!

Comment: https://www.chadgolden.com/blog/finding-all-the-permutations-of-an-array-in-c-sharp