# Вместо символов выводятся квадраты, помогите

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;
        Console.Write("Введите n : ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] mas = new int[n];
        char[] a = new char[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            mas[i] = i + 1;
            a[i] = (char)mas[i];
        }
        Permute(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Permute(char[] a, int i, int n)
    {
        int j;

        if (i == n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string(a));
        }
        else
        {
            char temp;
            for (j = i; j <= n; j++)
            {
                // swap(a[i], a[j]);
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;

                Permute(a, i + 1, n);

                // swap(a[i], a[j]);
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: зачем Вам здесь Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default; - вот эта строка?

Comment: Пытался таким образом пофиксить эту проблему, не получилось)\

Comment: А в чем, собственно, заключается задача? И что будет выводить, если char поменять на string?

Comment: Вы выводите символы с кодами 0, 1, 2 и т. д. Естественно, они отображаются квадратами. Уберите char, используйте int.

Comment: @РустамАлиев, скорее всего, получить все перестановки для множества размера N. На вход подаём размер множества, генерируем исходное множество (просто какое-нибудь. например, {1,2,3}). И получаем все его перестановки в Permute().

Comment: @MaxLevs , я это вижу и именно поэтому задал два вопроса - в чем суть задачи и что будет, если выводить строку, а не символ. Там по консоли сразу видно, где ошибся. Надеялся, что ТС сможет самостоятельно найти решение ;-)

Comment: @РустамАлиев https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1245569/373567 - "там всё сложно".

Comment: @aepot , мдя... хотя чего мы ожидали? Сессия же вроде как идёт))))) Те, кто (по их мнению) нас заменят  - сдают экзамен по будущей профессии )))))) Правда, я к этому времени успею уже несколько раз в гробу перевернуться ))))

Comment: @РустамАлиев ты не понимаешь, это другое! (с)

Comment: Удалось разобраться? Если да, отметьте ответ принятым, в случае если он был полезен.

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто перемудрили

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Введите n : ");
    string n = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] a = n.ToCharArray();
    Permute(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
Введите n : 123
123
132
213
231
321
312
```